# Why command iisreset leaves w3svc in stopping state

Tags: windows, iis, server

We have a series of Windows servers that are suddenly facing this issue when restarting iis.
There is no other issue in IIS and upon reboot all works well.
Please suggest if anyone is having a workaround for this issue.
OS : server 2008 R2
IIS: 7.5

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1239061.aspx?IISRESET+results+in+W3SVC+stuck+in+stopping+status+after+July+2018+patches

Comment: I checked it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was due to microsoft windows update that messed up the servers.
Uninstalled few culprit packages and now all works well !